# Python Uno Card Game

Tags: python

I am making an UNO card game and I generated and then shuffled a deck for it and each player is then given five cards from the shuffled deck. All the cards are supposed to be string objects in the lists but the wild card is being stored as a list object instead of a string object. I want it to be stored as a string.

```
import random

def buildDeck():
    deck = []
    colours = ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue"]
    values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "Draw Two", "Skip", "Reverse"]
    wilds = ["Wild", "Wild Draw Four"]
    
    for colour in colours:
        for value in values:
            cardVal = "{} {}".format(colour, value)
            deck.append(cardVal)
            if value != 0:
                deck.append(cardVal)
    
    for i in range(4):
        deck.append([wilds[0]])
        deck.append(wilds[1])
    
    return deck

def shuffleDeck(deck):
    for cardPos in range(len(deck)):
        randPos = random.randint(0, 107)
        deck[cardPos], deck[randPos] = deck[randPos], deck[cardPos]
    return deck

def drawCards(numCards):
    cardsDrawn = []
    for x in range (numCards):
        cardsDrawn.append(unoDeck.pop(0))
    return cardsDrawn

def showHand(player, playerHand):
    print("{}'s turn".format(player))
    print("Your Hand")
    print("-----------------------------")
    y = 1
    for card in playerHand:
        print("{}) {}".format(y, card))
        y += 1
    print("")

unoDeck = buildDeck()
unoDeck = shuffleDeck(unoDeck)
discards = []

players = [] #List to store player cards
playerNames = [] #List to store player names
colours = ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"]
numPlayers = None
print("Enter --help to display the rules of the game\n")

numPlayers = input("How many players? ")
if numPlayers == "--help" or numPlayers == "--resume":
    checkInput(numPlayers)
else:
    numPlayers = int(numPlayers)
    while len(playerNames) < numPlayers:
        tempName = input("Enter player's name: ")
        if tempName == "--help" or tempName == "--resume":
            checkInput(tempName)
        else:
            playerNames.append(tempName)
            players.append(drawCards(5))

print("The cards are:")
for (x,y) in zip(playerNames, players):
    print("Player {} has {}".format(x, y))
print("")
```

[Example here: Player Changmin's hand has the Wild card as a list not a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAzr6.png)

Comment: I think its because you’re doing deck.append([wilds[0]]) instead of deck.append(wilds[0]) in the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(4):
        deck.append([wilds[0]]) # <-- has extra brackets
        deck.append(wilds[1])
```

but this can also be simplified to

```
# build the rest of the deck

for i in range(4):
    deck += wilds
```

or

```
# build the rest of the deck

deck += wild * 4
```

also the `random` module has a built in `shuffle` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle which will do an inplace shuffle. so you can do:

```
uno_deck = buildDeck()
random.shuffle(uno_deck)
```

Answer (score 0):

For shuffling, use numpy module, `numpy.random.shuffle`. Also, write
`deck.append(wilds[0])`, instead of `deck.append([wilds[0]])`. In your example, you have added extra square brackets, causing python to think that it has to store the value inside a list in a list.